# $group and sum + add all greater than

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

Let's say my documents look like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "Example 1",
    year: "2012"
  },
  {
    name: "Example 2",
    year: "2012"
  },
  {
    name: "Example 3",
    year: "2013"
  },
  {
    name: "Example 4",
    year: "2014"
  }
]
```

Using an **aggregation**, is there a way to **group by year and sum the document count**, but additionally **add the sum of all later years**?

The **result** I want is this:

```
[
    {
        _id: "2012",
        count: 4 // years 2012-2014
    },
    {
        _id: "2013",
        count: 2 // years 2013-2014
    },
    {
        _id: "2014",
        count: 1 // only year 2014
    }
]
```

Right now, I'm using a normal `$group` + `$sum`, which gives me the counts for each year individually and then I sort them in JavaScript. I was hoping that there was a simpler way that gets rid of the additional JS code:

```
yearCounts: [           
    { $group: { _id: "$year", count: { $sum: 1 } } }
]
```

```
const yearCounts: { _id: string, count: number }[] = aggregationResult[0].yearCounts || [];
const yearCountsSummed = yearCounts.map((yearCount: { _id: string, count: number }) => {
    const yearsUntil = yearCounts.filter(year => year._id >= yearCount._id);
    const countSummed = yearsUntil.map(yearCount => yearCount.count).reduce((a, b) => a + b) || 0;
    return countSummed;
});
```

Comment: you want to sort with counter value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this was recently made quite easy using the [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) stage introduced in version 5.0 which allows us to do calculations over a "window" of documents (in your case all years), While in theory it's possible to do it with older operators as well I recommend against it as not only the syntax very messy but also the performance of such query will be abysmal. It will be easier to just group by year and then do the rest in code with a simple loop.

Anyways here is how to do it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$year",
      sum: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {
        _id: -1
      },
      output: {
        sum: {
          $sum: "$sum",
          window: {
            documents: [
              "unbounded",
              "current"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3Ht5ei7Vg-y)

Comment: Thank you, looks exactly like what I need. When I apply it to my project (with a more complex aggregation) I get an error I can't find in Google. Any idea what this means? `MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Requested document not in SpillableCache. Expected range was 0--1 but got 0`?

Comment: I'm assuming you are aggregating on a large collection with `allowDiskUse: true`, what is the storage engine you use? error related to [this ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-58877)

Comment: I use all the defaults, so I assume it's the **WiredTiger Storage Engine**

Comment: I've personally never seen this error, but it occurs either when trying to fetch a document from the cache (memory or disk) or when the storage engine tries to free up memory space (less likely). 
Can you try running the exact pipeline a few times to check which usecase it is? add a limit of 100k, 250k, 500k documents at the start - I imagine this will run on a low document sample.

Comment: There are actually only ~600 documents in this collection. I posted on the MongoDB forum, maybe someone there knows what this is about. I'll accept your answer because it's clearly the correct approach.

Comment: I found out that the error disappears when I make this operation the last step in my `facet` call (which creates several different operations). Any idea how `$setWindowFields` could be influencing other sections of a `facet`? I thought they were all independent of each other.

Comment: Where was this stage before the change?

Comment: This stage had two other ones happening after it, which both contained a `$group` with either `$sum` or `$addToset`. Here is the code if want to take a look: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/group-and-sum-add-all-greater-than/181319/3

Comment: If I reorder the year count (with`$setWindowFields`) as the last step, the error doesn't happen anymore. `$setWindowFields` must somehow interfere with the successive `$group` calls (even though they are separate face stages)

Comment: Could be interesting if you could provide a full pipeline that triggers the error- might be worth reporting as a BUG.

Comment: Gotcha. Unfortunately my whole aggregation call is over 200 lines long.

Answer (score -1):

Someone has given the answer, even though I am trying to give the other way.
As per desire result mentioned into the question. we can achieve result as below with aggregation with `$group ,$sort` pipeline.

[PlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2FAm0IPOzfV)

[image]

Hope, this solution might help or lead to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! But I actually don't only want to sort the results, I want to accumulate the count with the previous years.